# Copy complete node with attributes of an xml excluding the first element of node

Tags: xslt-1.0

XSLT: I am new to XSLT. I have to copy complete node of an XML excluding the first child of that node. Eg: Input is

```
    <root id="123456789">
      <userid></userid>
      <fname></fname>
      <lname></lname>
      <age></age>
    </root>

    Output should be:
    <root id="123456789">
      <fname></fname>
      <lname></lname>
      <age></age>
    </root>

    Please suggest how to achieve this. Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root id="123456789">
    <userid></userid>
    <fname></fname>
    <lname></lname>
    <age></age>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<root id="123456789">
      <fname/>
      <lname/>
      <age/>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.